# Resetting order number sequence in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I have tried to change the current order number in my Magento installation by running the following SQL query:

ALTER TABLE sequence_order_1 AUTO_INCREMENT = 2740000001;

My intention was to restart the order number sequence by setting a new starting value of 2740000001.

However, after running that query and checking what would be the next order number using:

SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'sequence_order_1';

The query still returns the previous value, not the new one I manually set.

Could you please indicate what I am doing wrong or what would be the correct way to restart the order number sequence in Magento 2? I need new orders to start with the new sequence beginning from 2740000001, but I have not managed to reflect that change after altering the auto increment value.

I would greatly appreciate if you can help me resolve this issue, or if you have any recommendation on the best way to reset the numbering in Magento.

Regards and thanks in advance for your reply.